# Ruby websocket check if user exist

Tags: ruby, websocket, sinatra, eventmachine

Using Event-machine and Ruby. Currently I'm making a game were at the end of the turn it checks if other user there. When sending data to the user using ws.send() how can I check if the user actually got the data or is alternative solution?

Comment: Usually you need to ping back over the socket to check that the remote is alive and not jammed.

Comment: Does ping have a callback to check if response happen. Like true or false?

Answer (score 2):

As the library doesn't provide you with access to the underlying protocol elements, you need to add elements to your application protocol to do this. A typical approach is to add an identifier to each message and response to messages with acknowledgement messages that contain those identifiers.

Note that such an approach will only help you to have a better idea of what has been received by a client. There is no assurance of particular state in the case of errors. An example would be losing a connection after the client as sent an ACK, but the service has not received it.

As a result of the complexity I just mentioned, it is often easier to try to make most operations idempotent - that is able to be replayed without detriment to the system, and to replay readily during/after error conditions. You may additionally find a way to periodically synchronize the relevant state entirely, to avoid the long term continuation of minor errors introduced by loss of data/a connection.

Comment: Gave thumbs up. I found the answer to my problem I used socket.state to determine if socket is closed or open and act on that response.